# Converting dates in Python

Tags: python

I have dates in the form `26/11/2015`. How can I convert them into the format `26-Nov-2015` and still keep them as dates and not strings?

Comment: Your question does not make much sense. If you keep them as dates, they have no format. The format is only manifested when you convert them to strings.

Comment: @tobias_k, would you, please, put that as an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your question does not make much sense. If you keep them as dates, they have no format. The format is only manifested when you convert them to strings.

So the answer is: Store the dates as `date` (or `datetime`) objects, and use `datetime.strftime` with some specific format whenever you need them as a string:

```
>>> from datetime import date
>>> d = date(2016, 11, 26)
>>> d.strftime("%Y/%m/%d")
'2016/11/26'
>>> d.strftime("%d-%b-%Y")
'26-Nov-2016'
```

Conversely, use `strptime` to parse strings in different formats to dates:

```
>>> datetime.datetime.strptime("26-Nov-2015", "%d-%b-%Y")
datetime.datetime(2015, 11, 26, 0, 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
from datetime import datetime

date = datetime.strptime('26/11/2015', '%d/%m/%Y')
print date.strftime("%d-%B-%Y")
```

In the above example, we are taking your input string 'dd/mm/yyyy' and turning it into a python datetime saving it to a variable called date (for future usage as per your request), and then printing it out in the format requested.

Answer (score 0):

You want to use the datetime module I think. For example:

```
from datetime import date
a = date(2015, 11, 26)
a.strftime("%A %d of %B, %Y")
```

should give you 'Thursday 26 of November, 2015'
Or for your specific formatting request:

```
a.strftime("%d-%b-%Y") #'26-Nov-2015'
```

Hope this helps, good luck!